# How to change table column titles of resource in laravel nova

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

I have a resources lets say Books with many different relationships.

I have a form with these fields

```
public function fields(Request $request)
{
    return [
        ID::make('id')
            ->sortable(),

        DateTime::make('Created At')
            ->format('HH:mm DD/MM/YY')
            ->sortable()
            ->exceptOnForms(),

        BelongsTo::make('Created by', 'user', User::class)
            ->onlyOnDetail(),

        Text::make('Title')
            ->sortable()
            ->rules('required', 'max:255'),
        BelongsTo::make('Network')
            ->sortable()
            ->rules('required', 'exists:networks,id'),
}
```

In index table I have,

```
ID, Created At, Created By, Title, Network
```

I want to change the `Network` title to something else. Is there a way to provide an alias for this? Or something without changing anything in the database or changing model names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`BelongsTo` constructor defined as `public function __construct($name, $attribute = null, $resource = null)`

Therefore try below code

`BelongsTo::make('Title you want', 'network', \App\Nova\Network::class)
            ->sortable()
            ->rules('required', 'exists:networks,id')`